# Need divs to be push down using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this code that is using jQuery, but I want to know is is possible to achieve the same result using only CSS. This is my code on Codepen: `https://codepen.io/dj-smoke-starboy/pen/REOgvj.`

I'm work on it but until now, I was not able to make it work just by using only css.

```js
$('.card').each(function(i) {
  $(this).fadeOut(1).delay(1000 * i).fadeIn(100)
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
}

.cardWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.card {
  background: #fff;
  animation: slide 0.5s linear both;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-5vh);
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    filter: blur(1em);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cardWrap">
  <div class="card">pushed DOWN</div>
  <div class="card">10 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">9 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">8 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">7 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">6 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">5 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">4 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">3 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">2 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">1 - Itin</div>

</div>
```

To achieve the same result that I'm getting by using JS and jQuery.

Comment: @Vickel this is not duplicate. This is must make only css, there made with jquery.

Comment: @DogukanCavus ok, retracted dup, sorry my mistake, being too fast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made again :)

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
}
.cardWrap {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column-reverse;
}
.card { 
  background:#fff; 
  animation: slide 0.5s linear both;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding:0;
  height:0px;
  width:0px;
  
}

.card:nth-child(1) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards .5s;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 1.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 2.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(4) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 3.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(5) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 4.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(6) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 5.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(7) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 6.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(8) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 7.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(9) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 8.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(10) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 9.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(11) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 10.5s;
}


@keyframes card1{
  to{opacity:1;height:auto;width:auto;padding:5px;margin-bottom: 1em;}
}
```

```html
<div class="cardWrap">
  <div class="card">pushed DOWN</div>
  <div class="card">10 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">9 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">8 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">7 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">6 - Itin</div>
   <div class="card">5 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">4 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">3 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">2 - Itin</div>
  <div class="card">1 - Itin</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dogukan Cavus, this is great, I have to create a loop for the .card:nth-child(i). do you know how to create one? Thankkkkkssss

Comment: Maybe makable with SCSS. But I don't know enough.

Comment: Thanks, I will check how to do it.