# Able to use a loop instead on Css, Less, scss

Tags: css, loops

I have this code:https://codepen.io/dj-smoke-starboy/pen/jXxJRd. And is working fine but I'm trying to use a loop on the css file to achieve the same result.

I have tried jQuery, it worked bu I still need to use a loop inside css or less file.

Html:

```
<div class="cardWrap">
  <div class="card">itin 1</div>
  <div class="card">itin 2</div>
  <div class="card">itin 3</div>
  <div class="card">itin 4</div>
  <div class="card">itin 5</div>
  <div class="card">itin 6</div>
  <div class="card">itin 7</div>
  <div class="card">itin 8</div>
  <div class="card">itin 9</div>
  <div class="card">itin 10</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
}

.cardWrap {
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column-reverse;
}

.card { 
  background:#fff; 
  margin-bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding:0;
  height:0px;
  width:0px;

}

.card:nth-child(1) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards .5s;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 1.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 2.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(4) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 3.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(5) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 4.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(6) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 5.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(7) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 6.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(8) {
 animation: card1 .3s forwards 7.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(9) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 8.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(10) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 9.5s;
}

.card:nth-child(11) {
  animation: card1 .3s forwards 10.5s;
}
@keyframes card1{
  to {
    opacity:1;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
   }
}
```

I expected to achieve the same result with a loop by using it inside of a css file or Less/scss

Comment: you simply pick code from your old question and you ask to add things? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223686/need-divs-to-be-push-down-using-only-css ... what did you try? it seems nothing

Comment: I tried a loop like this: @itineraries: 10;

.itin-loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {
  &:nth-type(@{i}) {
    animation-delay: ~"@{i}s";
  }
  .itin-loop(@i - 1);
 but Can't make it work.

Comment: show this on your question so we can correct you

Comment: Is a way to edit this question?

Comment: I kind of make it worked: https://codepen.io/dj-smoke-starboy/pen/LMvrro

Comment: [Edit] is how you edit questions.